FIX MANIFEST ISSUES Non-redirect URL failed Replace your URL with one that takes users directly to the app
I got an error message like this.Can someone help me to solve this problem?
As per google play console docs i have updated many time my manifest file but in Google play console -> [Select your app]->Grow -> Deep links getting above issue when click on web link right arrow.
I am also sending my manifest.xml file and actual screen shot of issue.
Screenshot having actual issue which is getting from google play console. Please review my manifest file and let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advanced.
(https://i.sstatic.net/T9NfFIJj.png)
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.learningstrategy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="learningstrategy" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:host="open" android:scheme="branchapp" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="mindtrx.app.link"
                android:path="/" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="mindtrx.app.link"
                android:path="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DRMModule.player.PlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/PlayerTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:scheme="asset" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".DRMModule.offline.AxDownloadService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.exoplayer.downloadService.action.RESTART" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.braze.push.BrazeFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".HeadlessTaskService" />
        <service android:name="com.reactnativecommunity.trackplayer.service.MediaPlaybackService" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey"
            android:value="key_live_************************" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test"
            android:value="key_test_************************" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoInitEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="fb" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="facebook" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Changed many times AndroidManifest file as per google play console document.
My expectation is that remove above warning from google play console in deep links path
FIX MANIFEST ISSUES
Non-redirect URL failed

How will the url in the screenshot you shared take users directly to your application?

@tomerpacific If i click on https://mindtrx.app.link/ this url then my app direct open without going to chrome and any other browser then also showing this warning. So what i want to do to remove this warning.

I placed mindtrx.app.link in Google Chrome, and it redirects to mindtrx.com. According to a Google Play warning, you should replace mindtrx.app.link with mindtrx.com in your app.
